# How do i loop through given two dates by hours in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to loop through two given dates by hour.
lets say two dates are start-2021-01-01_00 end 2021-01-01_23
it will print every hour like

2021-01-01_00

2021-01-01_01

...

2021-01-01_22

2021-01-01_23 etc.

Comment: What platform?  OSX (for instance) has different date options to linux/gnu.

Comment: unix and linux. @MrR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `date` command supports `-d` option, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

# convert yyyy-mm-dd_hh string into seconds since epoch
str2epoch() {
    date -d "${1/_/ }" +%s
}
start="2021-01-01_00"
end="2021-01-01_23"

for (( i = $(str2epoch "$start"); i <= $(str2epoch "$end"); i+=3600 )); do
    date -d "@$i" +%y-%m-%d_%H
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Different platforms have different versions of the date command - so actual commands may be slightly different (example below BSD/OSX giving results in UTC).

The basic idea is to get your start and end date/time as seconds since epoc - then you can just add +3600 for each hour using a simple for loop.

Then you can just do a simple for loop.. e.g

```
DATEB4=0      # 1/1/1970 00:00 GMT
DATEAF=176400 # 3/1/1970 01:00 GMT

CURR=$DATEB4
while [[ "$CURR" -le "$DATEAF" ]]; do
  date -r "$CURR" -u
  let CURR=$CURR+3600
done
```

Of course this doesn't work with leap seconds, and a few other cases ...

Here's some output

```
Thu  1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Thu  1 Jan 1970 01:00:00 UTC
Thu  1 Jan 1970 02:00:00 UTC
Thu  1 Jan 1970 03:00:00 UTC
....
Fri  2 Jan 1970 18:00:00 UTC
Fri  2 Jan 1970 19:00:00 UTC
Fri  2 Jan 1970 20:00:00 UTC
Fri  2 Jan 1970 21:00:00 UTC
Fri  2 Jan 1970 22:00:00 UTC
Fri  2 Jan 1970 23:00:00 UTC
Sat  3 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Sat  3 Jan 1970 01:00:00 UTC
```

Leave the fun formatting to you ..

Comment: linux - try `date -d '@2147483647'` for gnu date (close to date -r but not exactly the same).